# Difference between rules and rules1.14 in Prometheus operator

Tags: prometheus-operator

What is the difference between rules and rules1.14 in Prometheus operator? When is rules or rules1.14 used?

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus .

I see both have same rules but with some differences.Like CPUThrottlingHIGH rule exist in both folders but rules1.14 has it as "info" and rules folder has it as "warning".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1.14` term is referring to the Kubernetes version.

When your Kubernetes version is in `1.10 <= version <1.14`, rules from [rules](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/rules) directory is created.

You will find the following line at the beginning of every YAML files in the `rules` directory:

```
{{- if and (semverCompare ">=1.10.0-0" $kubeTargetVersion) (semverCompare "<1.14.0-0" $kubeTargetVersion) .Values.defaultRules.create .Values.defaultRules.rules.alertmanager }}
```

Similarly, when your Kubernetes version is in `version >= 1.14`, rules from [rules-1.14](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/templates/prometheus/rules-1.14) directory is created.

```
{{- if and (semverCompare ">=1.14.0-0" $kubeTargetVersion) (semverCompare "<9.9.9-9" $kubeTargetVersion) .Values.defaultRules.create .Values.kubeEtcd.enabled .Values.defaultRules.rules.etcd }}
```

Comment: Thanks much..One query though..For CPUThrottlingHigh alert,its defined as "info" in rules1.14 and warning in rules.We are using Kubernetes 1.15 version.In the Prometheus alerts page,we are seeing "info" which makes sense as it is from rules1.14.However when we receive the alerts,sometimes we are receving "info" and sometimes "warning" for CPUThrottlingHigh alert.Not sure why its happening this way.Could you please clarify if you have idea?

Comment: You can list all your registered rules `curl http://localhost:9090/api/v1/rules`, check which one is there or both.